# removing data which are not refenceing to other table POSTGRES

Tags: postgresql

I have one table USER and some other tables like USER_DETAILS ,USER_QUALIFICATION etc USER_ID references to all such table i want to remove those USER_ID which are not present in any other tables.

Comment: See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-delete.html

Answer (score 0):

Deleting all of the users that are not present in a connected table:

`DELETE FROM table WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM other_table)`

If you want to delete only users that are not found in any table than you can add

`AND NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM another_table)`

Alternatively you can create a tmp table and merge in all the user_ids that you want to keep and use that table in the sub-select for the NOT IN.

Comment: There are around 108 table to write query for each take much time

Answer (score 0):

Use a `DELETE` with a `not exists` condition for all related tables:

```
delete from "USER" u
where not exists (select *
                  from user_details ud
                  where ud.user_id = u.user_id)
  and not exists (select *
                  from user_qualification uq 
                  where uq.user_id = u.user_id);
```

---

Note that `user` is a reserved word, and thus needs to be quoted to be usable as a table name. But quoting makes it case-sensitive. So `"USER"` and `"user"` are two *different* table names. As you have not included the DDL for your tables I cannot tell if your table is named `"USER"` or `"user"`.

In general I would strongly recommend to avoid using double quotes for identifies completely.

Comment: There are around 108 table to write query for each take much time